# is there any image effect to add white background in the image in drupal 7

Tags: image, drupal-7, styles, effect

Drupal 7 module 'image style' can make image effect such as resize,scale,crop etc.But it's not enough. For example, the original image size is 800x600, I can scale it to 400x300, then I want to  add white background in height, make it 400x400. How to make this effect?

Comment: Why not use CSS to apply a 50px border to the top and bottom of the image?

Comment: @jsheffers because the image height is not fixed

Comment: You are saying that you are scaling the image to 400x300 that is a fixed size... If that was the case you could use my solution above.

Comment: Use image cache actions, with these effects:

* Scale 400x400 (upscaling allowed)
* Define canvas 400x400 (center, center)  #ffffff  under image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I created [image effect module](http://drupal.org/sandbox/drupalfan79/1941430) for this. it resizes an image to an exact set of dimensions size without any crop, stretch, or shrunk, but will add white background if need.

Answer (score 11):

[image cache actions](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions/) is a great module for such cases... you can try that

Comment: For this, use 2 styles: Scale + Define canvas under image

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can do this easily with **Image Kit effect**. Using the **Smart Resizer**, you can define which background color you want to use to fill blanks.

https://www.drupal.org/project/iek

Comment: instead of just posting a link you should show answer using code example and briefly describe to enrich an answer

Answer (score 1):

I see you have found a solution. But there is a much simpler one. Make your image style scale your image to 400x300 (it will keep the aspect ratio of the image). Then use CSS to style one of the surrounding divs with a white background and a fixed size - 400x300px. If an image has a different aspect ratio, the surrounding white div will fill in. If you want to add white space to the bottom/right, position your image to the top left inside the div. Or you could center the image to add white space to both sides or top/bottom (depending on the aspect ratio of the image). If you need a border or box-shadow around the image, apply it to the surrounding div.

**Add black space**:
If your image style are used in a responsive slideshow or something and/or you want all images to be an exact size (height/width), you could achieve this by using two filters:

- **Scale** to 400x300 (hight or width will match this size and the other will be equal or smaller)
- **Crop** to 400x300 (since height/width already is equal or smaller than 400x300 it will add black space top/bottom or right/left if needed)

[edit]

**Add white space** using [ImageCache Actions](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) (Drupal 7):

[See this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21308/change-image-background-colour-when-cropping#21309)

For Drupal 8 ImageCache Actions is now called [Image Effects](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_effects). The effect to fix height/width with background option is "Set canvas".